# GWT Remote debugging and logging

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am running a GWT app on windows machine but I have added bindAddress parameter to run configuration.I am doing following steps after doing full GWT compile in eclipse

1) run configurations -> run
2) from URL http://xxx.ccc.qqq.ddd:8888/GWT_App.html?gwt.codesvr=xxx.ccc.qqq.ddd:9997
   I remove gwt.codesvr parameter.
3) I now the paste the new URL http://xxx.ccc.qqq.ddd:8888/GWT_App.html in my ipad's browser

I have used the GWT logging but i cant see the log statements in my eclipse's console window, can anybody please help?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rohit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the gwt.codesvr, GWT will use the compiled version of GWT.
GWT.log is logging only in developpement mode.

In GWT you can use the java framework log, and configure differents loggers (In browser console, remote logging, popup logger)
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html

With iPad, you can use the popup logger and remote logging for see yours loggs.